# use matplotlib color map for color cycle

Tags: python, matplotlib

If I create colors by e.g:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

n = 6
color = plt.cm.coolwarm(np.linspace(0.1,0.9,n))
color
```

color is a numpy array:

```
array([[ 0.34832334,  0.46571115,  0.88834616,  1.        ],
       [ 0.56518158,  0.69943844,  0.99663507,  1.        ],
       [ 0.77737753,  0.84092121,  0.9461493 ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.93577377,  0.8122367 ,  0.74715647,  1.        ],
       [ 0.96049006,  0.61627642,  0.4954666 ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.83936494,  0.32185622,  0.26492398,  1.        ]])
```

However, If I plug in the RGB values (without the alpha value 1) as tuples in my `.mplstyle` file (`map(tuple,color[:,0:-1])`), I get an error similar to this one:

```
in file "/home/moritz/.config/matplotlib/stylelib/ggplot.mplstyle"
    Key axes.color_cycle: [(0.34832334141176474 does not look like a color arg
  (val, error_details, msg))
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: a color arg should start with `(` not with `[(`, yes?

Comment: Still does not work. I tried ( (...), (...) ) ; (...), (...); (...)  (...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit 04/2021:** As of matplotlib 2.2.0, the key `axes.color_cycle` has been deprecated ([source: API changes](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/prev_api_changes/api_changes_2.2.0.html#id1)).
The new method is to use `set_prop_cycle` ([source: matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_prop_cycle API](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_prop_cycle.html))

---

The details are in the matplotlibrc itself, actually: it needs a string rep (hex or letter or word, not tuple).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1,1)

ys = np.random.random((5, 6))
ax1.plot(range(5), ys)
ax1.set_title('Default color cycle')
plt.show()

# From the sample matplotlibrc:
#axes.color_cycle    : b, g, r, c, m, y, k  # color cycle for plot lines
                                            # as list of string colorspecs:
                                            # single letter, long name, or
                                            # web-style hex

# setting color cycle after calling plt.subplots doesn't "take"
# try some hex values as **string** colorspecs
mpl.rcParams['axes.color_cycle'] = ['#129845','#271254', '#FA4411', '#098765', '#000009']

fig, ax2 = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax2.plot(range(5), ys)
ax2.set_title('New color cycle')


n = 6
color = plt.cm.coolwarm(np.linspace(0.1,0.9,n)) # This returns RGBA; convert:
hexcolor = map(lambda rgb:'#%02x%02x%02x' % (rgb[0]*255,rgb[1]*255,rgb[2]*255),
               tuple(color[:,0:-1]))

mpl.rcParams['axes.color_cycle'] = hexcolor

fig, ax3 = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax3.plot(range(5), ys)
ax3.set_title('Color cycle from colormap')

plt.show()
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 37):

### "Continuous" colormap

If you want to cycle through `N` colors from a "continous" colormap, like e.g. the default viridis map, [the solution by @Gerges](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51166216/4124317) works nicely.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 6
plt.rcParams["axes.prop_cycle"] = plt.cycler("color", plt.cm.viridis(np.linspace(0,1,N)))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i in range(N):
    ax.plot([0,1], [i, 2*i])

plt.show()
```

### "Discrete" colormap

Matplotlib provides a few colormap that are "discrete" in the sense that they hold some low number of distinct colors for qualitative visuals, like the `tab10` colormap. To cycle through such colormap, the solution might be to not use `N` but just port all colors of the map to the cycler.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams["axes.prop_cycle"] = plt.cycler("color", plt.cm.tab20c.colors)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i in range(15):
    ax.plot([0,1], [i, 2*i])

plt.show()
```

Note that only `ListedColormaps` have the `.colors` attribute, so this only works for those colormap, but not e.g. the `jet` map.

### Combined solution

The following is a general purpose function that takes a colormap as input and outputs a corresponding cycler. I originally proposed this solution in [this matplotlib issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/10840#issuecomment-374772117).

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import cycler
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap, ListedColormap
import matplotlib.cm

def get_cycle(cmap, N=None, use_index="auto"):
    if isinstance(cmap, str):
        if use_index == "auto":
            if cmap in ['Pastel1', 'Pastel2', 'Paired', 'Accent',
                        'Dark2', 'Set1', 'Set2', 'Set3',
                        'tab10', 'tab20', 'tab20b', 'tab20c']:
                use_index=True
            else:
                use_index=False
        cmap = matplotlib.cm.get_cmap(cmap)
    if not N:
        N = cmap.N
    if use_index=="auto":
        if cmap.N > 100:
            use_index=False
        elif isinstance(cmap, LinearSegmentedColormap):
            use_index=False
        elif isinstance(cmap, ListedColormap):
            use_index=True
    if use_index:
        ind = np.arange(int(N)) % cmap.N
        return cycler("color",cmap(ind))
    else:
        colors = cmap(np.linspace(0,1,N))
        return cycler("color",colors)
```

Usage for the "continuous" case:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
N = 6
plt.rcParams["axes.prop_cycle"] = get_cycle("viridis", N)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i in range(N):
    ax.plot([0,1], [i, 2*i])

plt.show()
```

Usage for the "discrete" case

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams["axes.prop_cycle"] = get_cycle("tab20c")

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i in range(15):
    ax.plot([0,1], [i, 2*i])

plt.show()
```

Comment: `plt.rcParams["axes.prop_cycle"] = plt.cycler("color", plt.cm.tab20c.colors)` was the line I was looking for!

Comment: this is great! thank you for the combined solution!

Answer (score 35):

For Matplotlib 2.2, using the `cycler` module will do the trick, without the need to convert to Hex values.

```
import cycler

n = 100
color = pyplot.cm.viridis(np.linspace(0, 1,n))
mpl.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'] = cycler.cycler('color', color)
```

Comment: Note that I needed to change `pyplot.cm` to `plt.cm` and `mpl.rcParams` to `plt.rcParams` because I did `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` as is conventional.

Answer (score 2):

**TLDR**:

For those looking to retrieving single color from `cmap`, use `cmap.colors[INDEX]` instead of `cmap[INDEX]`.

---

Following on how to create `cmap` from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60853953/11671779):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import numpy as np

cmap = matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(matplotlib.colormaps["Set3"].colors)
plt.scatter(np.random.uniform(0, 10, 50), np.random.uniform(0, 10, 50), c=np.random.uniform(0, 10, 50), cmap=cmap)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

You can slice the color to be stored on `cmap` using something like `matplotlib.colormaps["Set3"].colors[:5]`. You can retrieve single color using `cmap.colors[INDEX]`, such as `cmap.colors[0]`.

```py
print(cmap.colors[0])
plt.plot(np.random.uniform(0, 10, 50), color=cmap.colors[0], label=cmap.colors[0])
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

*old, deprecated solution*,

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import numpy as np

cmap = matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(matplotlib.cm.get_cmap("Set3").colors[:5])
plt.scatter(np.random.uniform(0, 10, 50), np.random.uniform(0, 10, 50), c=np.random.uniform(0, 10, 50), cmap=cmap)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

---

**EDIT 1**

Now, you can see the color palette using,

```py
matplotlib.colormaps["Set3"]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want something locally defined, you can add before plotting:

```
fig, ax4 = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax4.set_prop_cycle(color=plt.cm.plasma(np.linspace(0, 1, n))
ax4.plot(range(5), ys)
ax4.set_title('Color cycle from colormap (local)')
```