# Gradient color plot in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I am coding a python app which collects temperature and time from a wireless sensor network.

Briefly a snippet of my code is like this:

```
a.set_facecolor((0.9, 0.9, 1.0))
myFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M')
a.xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)
a.xaxis_date()
a.set_title('WSN temperature')
a.set_ylabel('Temp ' + u"\u2103")
a.set_xlabel('Time')
a.grid(True)
a.set_ylim([-20, 40])   #values found in the collectsensor.py
a.yaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(-20, 40, 5))
a.set_xlim([timeIntervalLeft, timeIntervalRight])

cmap = clr.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("", ["darkblue", "blue", "violet", "yellow", "orange", "red"])
cmap2 = clr.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("", ["red", "orange", "yellow", "violet", "blue", "darkblue"])

a.scatter(timeList, tempList, c=tempList, s=100, cmap=cmap)

y = tempList
s = pd.Series(y, index=timeList)

# convert dates to numbers first
inxval = mdates.date2num(s.index.to_pydatetime())
points = np.array([inxval, s.values]).T.reshape(-1, 1, 2)

segments = np.concatenate([points[:-1], points[1:]], axis=1)

lc = LineCollection(segments, cmap=cmap2, linewidth=3)
lc.set_array(inxval)
a.add_collection(lc)
```

With that code I obtain something like:

[image]

You can see that scatter can make use of cmap, so the dots become "hotter" as the y values increase. I looked for something similar for the plot function but I have not found anything that could work for me.

Thanks to ImportanceOfBeingErnest I noticed that previous question [How to plot multi-color line if x-axis is date time index of pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44642966/how-to-plot-multi-color-line-if-x-axis-is-date-time-index-of-pandas)

But here the color is not really related to the temperature in y axes, but it is distributed along all the cmap color.

Comment: Do you mean something like [``plt.cm.coolwarm(v)``](https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38208700/matplotlib-plot-lines-with-colors-through-colormap

Comment: @Dadep I saw that, but I have only one plot instead of many

Comment: @Jurgy can you make me an example on how to use it in my code? Thanks

Comment: In addition to [the duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44642966/how-to-plot-multi-color-line-if-x-axis-is-date-time-index-of-pandas) also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47851492/plot-curve-with-blending-line-colors-with-matplotlib-pyplot) for possible optimizations.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I am tryng to implement something similar to your first link solution, but the problem is that the gradiend is not in the right way(colder is red) and mostly the rainbow of color is distributed to all segments to cover all the colors of the plasma cmap, but it is not related to the temperature of y axes

Comment: Feel free to ask a specific question about the problem you face, applying a known solution. In the current question you haven't even tried to use a LineCollection. Also note that such question need to have a [mcve] of the issue present. But first try to understand the linked solution, since you are completely free which array to use for the colors.

Comment: Why are you using `lc.set_array(inxval)`? `inxval` are the dates and has nothing to do with temperature.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest thanks so much. I was having some trouble because I used a python list instead of a numpy array. Now I solved qith something like:                                       arr = np.array(tempList)
    lc.set_array(arr)
    a.add_collection(lc)

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest the only thing is that it works good only if points are near together. I do not know why but if I manually add more values the segments keep remaining blue.

Comment: Mind that [mcve]s are indispensible when communicating about code. In total this seems to be a different problem. So create a [mcve] of the issue and ask a question about it.