# Plot the change in time of different items

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Good Evening,

I have the following dataframe, containing different products in the item column, and their sales ranking, across three months (7-8-9):

```
print(df)

           item                           RANKING
month                                         
7          PRODUCT_1                         1
7          PRODUCT_2                         2
(...)  
8          PRODUCT_1                         4
8          PRODUCT_2                         3
(...)  
9          PRODUCT_1                         1
9          PRODUCT_2                         2
```

I would like to plot the change in ranking, in the three months, for each product, as a line.

Specifically, on th **x-axis** the **months** (7-8-9), on the **y-axis on the left** the name of the **product**, and ultimately **y-axis on the right** the **position/rank** of it.

I tried with:

```
df = df.set_index('month')

plt.figure(figsize=(12,5))

plt.plot(df["RANKING"],
         label = "Position")

plt.plot(df["item"],
         label = "Product")

plt.legend(loc = "upper right")
plt.xticks(rotation = 60)
plt.show()
```

But it doesn't display it as described before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
products = sorted(set(df['item']))

plt.figure(figsize=(20,5))

for product in products:

    data = df.loc[df['item']==product].sort_values('month')

    X = data['month'].values
    y = data['RANKING'].values

    plt.plot(X,y)

plt.legend(products)
```

hope it helps!

Comment: It did help indeed! Is there a way to order the y-axis (RANKING) from low (first place) to high (last place in df)? I tried with df.loc[df['item']==product] .sort_values(["month", "RANKING"], ascending=[True, True]) but it didn't work.

Comment: well.. you can sort it in different ways.. but if you want to sort by ranking, you have to pick a month in which the ranking is to be sorted by (one item can be first in the month 7 but last in the month 9 - how do you sort it?)

Comment: More importantly, a few colors overlap; for instance, two orange lines appear. How would you suggest to fix this issue?

Comment: an easy way to fix that is to use a cmap; see this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38208700/matplotlib-plot-lines-with-colors-through-colormap

Comment: Thank you @epattaro