# Color by value from a chosen colormap in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I dig into several questions, to find an answer for the condition that one want to plot several lines in a plot and choose colors from a given colormap and colors are choosen by a third variable value.

some thing like this:

```
color = ['0.1', '0.8']

for i in range(2):
    x = np.arange(0, 10, 0.1)
    y = np.sin(x*(i+1))
    pl.plot(x, y, c=color[i])
```

But here I can only have colors from `gray` colormap.

Another option:

```
from cycler import cycler
NUM_COLORS = 10
cm = pl.get_cmap('gist_rainbow')
ax.set_prop_cycle(cycler('color', [cm(1.*ii/NUM_COLORS)
                                    for ii in range(NUM_COLORS)]))
```

here it is possible to pick a colormap, but I have no control on the order of colors and colors are chosen by the order of lines that are plotted.

Do we have some thing like this:

```
# a command to choose colormap comes here

for i in range(2):
    x = np.arange(0, 10, 0.1)
    y = np.sin(x*(i+1))
    pl.plot(x, y, c=(i or some operation on i to choose color based on index))
```

Comment: You can of course use *any*  colormap. Did you see [Matplotlib Plot Lines with Colors Through Colormap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38208700/matplotlib-plot-lines-with-colors-through-colormap)

Comment: YES! exactly  what I was looking for.