# Is there a simple way to plot related traces with similar colors in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have multiple measurements from three different sensors. I want to plot all measurements from sensor A in a bluish color, from sensor B in a yellowish and from sensor C in a redish color.

Is there a simple way to achive this with matplotlib, i.e. different colormaps or something?

I plotted related measurements in the same color, but then I can't distinguish the different measurements. I could create my own colormaps, but that seems tedious.

My data looks something like this:

Measurement 1:

| Time | Sensor A | Sensor B | Sensor C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 h | 20°C | 18°C | 16°C |
| 1 h | 21°C | 19°C | 16°C |
| 2 h | 20°C | 19°C | 17°C |

Measurement 2:

| Time | Sensor A | Sensor B | Sensor C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 h | 19°C | 19°C | 15°C |
| 1 h | 21°C | 18°C | 16°C |
| 2 h | 20°C | 19°C | 14°C |

Measurement 3:

| Time | Sensor A | Sensor B | Sensor C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 h | 21°C | 18°C | 16°C |
| 1 h | 22°C | 19°C | 16°C |
| 2 h | 20°C | 19°C | 17°C |

[image]

Comment: Would you make your question more specific, include some example data, and what you expect the final plot to look like? For example, it's unclear what you are calling "traces".

Comment: I edited it. Is it clearer now?

Comment: It is clearer! Would you also include an image of what your current plot looks like?

Comment: Seems like the [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38208700/matplotlib-plot-lines-with-colors-through-colormap) will help. You can loop over your measurement and sensor combinations to color them closely.

Comment: Can you please use markup tables? You're almost there! See [/editing-help#tables](/editing-help#tables) for how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the link in my comment, you can loop over the sensor-measurement combinations to create a colormap based on Matplotlib's existing `RdYlBu`.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.pylab as pyl
import numpy as np
from itertools import product

measurement_list = [df1, df2, df3] # The 3 measurement dataframes from your example
sensor_list = sorted(df1.filter(like='Sensor').columns)

# n is the number of sensors x the number of measurements
n = len(measurement_list) * len(sensor_list)

# Use the reverse order of RdYlBu to get the color combination you specified
colors = pyl.cm.RdYlBu_r([0.1,0.15,0.2,0.5,0.5,0.55,0.6, 0.85,0.9,0.95]) # play around with to get the boundaries and number you need
# Be less specific with color boundaries and just get the number you want
#colors = pyl.cm.RdYlBu_r(np.linspace(0,1,n)) 

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,6))

# Get the combinations without replacement of the sensor-measurement pairs
ms_combos = product(sensor_list, measurement_list)

for idx, (sensor, df) in enumerate(ms_combos):
    # Plot each sensor's readings and label by sensor and measurement
    ax.plot(df['Time'], df[sensor], color = colors[idx], label = f'{sensor} - Meas. {idx%3+1}')
    
ax.set(xlabel = 'Time [h]', ylabel = 'Temperature [C]')
ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

I think it would be easier to use different `linestyles` or `markers` for different measurements. It depends on whether it is more important to compare different sensors in one measurement or the same sensor data in different measurements.

**Old answer**

You should be able to simply supply colors so you get lines in three different colors by calling the `plot` function three times with the `color` argument:

```
from matploltib import pyplot as plt

plt.plot(x_A, y_A, color='r')
plt.plot(x_B, y_B, color='g')
plt.plot(x_C, y_C, color='b')
```

Comment: I know that, but I have multiple plots for every sensor and looking for a way to not choose the color manually but to say matplotlib something like: Plot traces from sensor A in bluish colors, from sensor B in yellowish and so forth