# Using a colormap for matplotlib line plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, colormap

I’d like to employ the reverse Spectral `colormap` ,

https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html

for a lineplot.

This works fine with a hex bin plot::

```
color_map = plt.cm.Spectral_r
image = plt.hexbin(x,y,cmap=color_map)
```

but when I do

```
ax1.plot(x,y, cmp=color_map)
```

this gives me::

> AttributeError: Unknown property cmap

Note, I just want to set the `colormap` and let `matplotliob` do the rest; i.e. I don't want to have a `color=' argument` in the .plot command.

Comment: Unfortunately it is unclear what the desired output of something like `ax.plot(x,y, cmap=color_map)` should be. `plot` does not have a `cmap` argument; most certainly because it is not clear what quantity should be colormapped in a line plot. If you can tell what the desired output should be, there might be a goodalternative.

Comment: Why the heck did this get downvoted??!!

Comment: While I did not downvote, the reason other people did is most certainly explained by my comment. You should update your question as to include the desired behaviour because as it stands it is not clear what you are expecting to happen when using the (non-existant) `cmap` argument.

Comment: I still don't understand why this is getting down-voted!! I was just keen to employ a nice colormap scheme to my line plots!! Eeeks!!!

Comment: You still haven't said what you expect.

Comment: Well, what I expected is that by default the line would be colormapped according t the y-axis, and there would be an option to color the lines by the x-axis...I'm still looking for how to color a lineplot based on x-axis values.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can have a look at this solution - the third variant is what you want:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57227821/5972778

You need to know how many lines you're plotting in advance, as otherwise it doesn't know how to choose the colours from the range.

Answer (score 6):

I think that seaborn's [`color_palette` function](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.color_palette.html#seaborn.color_palette) is very convenient for this purpose. It can be used in a `with` statement to temporarily set the color cycle for a plot or set of plots.
For example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

with sns.color_palette("Spectral", n_colors=10):
    plt.plot(np.random.rand(5, 10))
```

You can use with any predefined [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html) or [seaborn colormap](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/color_palettes.html#palette-tutorial), or provide a custom sequence of colors.

Comment: While this is convenient, it seems to affect also subsequent lines added to the same plot outside of the with clause.

Comment: It's a very game changing way to set colours. Thanks @astoeriko !

Comment: unfortunately it does not seem to work for a plt.scatter()

Comment: it does not work in subplots ?

Comment: @PierreL For plt.scatter plots you can use the `c` and/or `cmap` keyword arguments. What do you mean with “it does not work in subplots”? Using different color maps in different subplots?

Comment: It seems to me that it does not work if I add a plt.subplot(), even without color change between subplots.