# How to use colormap in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, data-analysis, colormap

I've spent too many hours trying to figure out how to use pre-made colormap or color palette for my plots in Python. How does one change the colormap for his plots? Is there some simple way of doing it?

I did try to use function such as

```py
plt.set_cmap('Set1')
```

but I'm using it wrong I guess. Here's the code I want the palette to be changed in:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
for i in range(10):
    plt.plot([0,1],[i,i])
plt.show()
```

I made workaround for now, but I would be pleased if someone came up with a real solution.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

colors = ["#1f77b4","#ff7f0e","#2ca02c","#f61600","#7834a9",
"#17becf","#684427","#fa5deb","#17becf","#17becf"]

for i in range(10):
    plot.plt([0,1],[i,i], color = colors[i])
plt.show()
```

The task is simple, change the default color palette to one of these qualitative ones (e.g. 'Set1', 'tab20'): 
https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html

Comment: See also: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/color/color_cycler.html#sphx-glr-gallery-color-color-cycler-py

Comment: [This new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57227821/4124317) to the first duplicate directly shows the usage of the the qualitative colormaps.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, your link does not answer the question of how to simply use the colour map.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it help but a similar question had been asked here : [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16834861/create-own-colormap-using-matplotlib-and-plot-color-scale)

EDIT : Here is all pre-made colormap :[image]

Comment: The problem is I think that scatter plots has the default argument for cmap, if you use plt.plot() it doesn't have that. The data I'm visualizing is connected via lines. I need that every plot has different solid color, but not from the default palette.

Comment: This is a nice list of colour maps, but it does not answer the question how to actually use them.
What commands do I have to use to use these predefined colour maps.

The link you posted is about how to make your own colour map. But I already don't know how to use the predefined ones.