# Is it possible to control which colors are retrieved from matplotlib colormap?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors

I want to assign colors in a plot to nominal data represented by integers. I want to draw colors from a Qualitative colormap, specifically I want to draw five colors from Set3:

[image: Matplotlib built-in Qualitative colormaps]

The problem is that I want to use the first five colors, but the colormapper normalizes my data, which ranges from 1 to 5 for the five categorical values, and selects the 1st, 4th, 7th, 10th, and 12th colors from the 12-color set.

Basically, `matplotlib.cm.get_cmap` allows you to specify a number of colors, but normalizes across the range:

```py
from matplotlib import cm
set3_5 = cm.get_cmap("Set3", lut = 5)
```

I want something like `matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap` which has a parameter `N` which *truncates* the color list after *N* items without normalizing. But I can't figure out how to pass a built-in colormap to `ListedColormap`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With `cm.get_cmap("Set3").colors` you get a list of the 12 colors in the colormap. This list can be sliced to get specific colors. It can be used as input for the `ListedColormap`.

Note that with a sequential colormap such as viridis, the list has 256 colors. You can get an evenly spaced subset with `cm.get_cmap("viridis", 8).colors` and then again take a slice, for example if you don't want to use the too bright colors.

Here is an example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import numpy as np

cmap = matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(matplotlib.cm.get_cmap("Set3").colors[:5])
plt.scatter(np.random.uniform(0, 10, 50), np.random.uniform(0, 10, 50), c=np.random.uniform(0, 10, 50), cmap=cmap)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image: example]